# Manage dependencies for multiple Python projects in monorepo

Tags: python, dependency-management, monorepo

**Disclaimer:** the question may seem like an opinion-based one, but the main goal is **to prove one of approaches with standards or style guides**.

### Problem

Say we have a monorepo with two completely independent Python projects. Some dependencies are shared, some are project specific.

### Questions

- does it make sense to use shared dependencies list (requirements.txt, poetry.lock, etc.) for the whole repo?
- are there any PEPs or other widely used guides that regulate this?

### Pros and cons

As for me, the advantages of using **isolated dependencies** are:

- simpler dependency resolving - sub-dependency constraints specific for one project won't affect others. Also, old specific packages may be completely incompatible with modern because of conflicting sub-dependencies
- lower risk of unexpected regression issues - otherwise changing project-specific package may cause sub-dependency update and issues with one which doesn't use that package at all

And the disadvantage of isolated deps is a technical debt caused by diverged versions of shared dependencies - a package may be bumped in one of the projects, but others would keep using the older version. And this variance would likely increase over time.

Of course, **I'd appreciate other thoughts** on these options. And again, are there any Python or general guides on this?

Comment: [This](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/external.html) is how it is handled by Bazel

Comment: Also, my unsolicited opinion: in most circumstances, monorepository is a terrible idea

Comment: @Marat thanks for the reference, interesting concept